# How to go about having a view model to help create the view, and another to represent a submitted form's data

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

This is in ASP.NET Core MVC. I have a support request form page (view) that is created from data pulled from a database. I get that data in the `GET` method and create a view model containing the form's title and description, which team the form goes to, etc. This model is essentially used to help build the form page. Let's call it `GetViewModel`.

If the form is submitted, I want to have a view model (let's call it `PostViewModel`) to help validate the form's user data, however, this means that the view in question now deals with two different view models and the `asp-for` tag helper only looks at the `GetViewModel`, which is passed to the view from the corresponding `GET` method.

I guess my idea was to have two view models to keep a separation since one is helping and one is for validation, but I'm wondering if this is just messy and the best approach is to use a single view model that handles everything.

Comment: I'm curious that what differences should be between `GetViewModel` and `PostViewModel`? In my humble opinion, your requirment looks like to have a "data edit" page, which would query data from DB first and list in the form in a view, then when after we modify the data, we click the button to submit the data into database so that the data is updated. In this scenario, GetModel and PostModel should be the same.. Could you pls expain more about it? By the way, here's [a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc) for mvc post data, its helpful maybe.